# Can I make two columns unique to each other?

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I'm just playing around with mysql and learning as I go along.  Here's my problem.  I have a table(in python) with number values(for example {3:1,3:2,3:3}).  I want to use the database as persistence storage of this variables(as they don't fully fit in memory) but I want to try to make it as fast as possible.

Currently I am just using one column(indexed) in mysql and each entry in the dictionary gets its own row.  I wanted to try to see if I could speed up reads/writes if I used two columns of INT as opposed to a CHAR column, but I need both columns to be unique to each other.  In the example above all the data is unique and if I add another 3=1, then it'll just overwrite the existing value, but 3=4 would create a new entry.  How can I replicate that in mysql?

Also does my logic about the speed up make sense or will the select on two columns actually end up being more expensive than having one?

I'm building this from scratch so you don't have to work within my existing solution, I'm very flexible to take any approach that works.

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for composite primary key?

Comment: I would suggest splitting the `varchar` into two `ints`... not for performance reasons, but for [proper normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  First, Make it work - second, make it right - lastly, worry about making it fast.

Comment: @Asdfg I think so, right now I only have one column so I want to see if I can split it.
@ Michael I'm trying to give it a shot. Right now it already works but I feel mysql could be faster so I'm just testing different approaches and benchmarking it against previous results(and making sure results are the same)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version is that you can have multiple columns in a unique index

```
// Create the test table
CREATE TABLE testTable (
    col1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    col2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    col3 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2)
);
```

That will add a column with name `uniqueOnCol1AndCol2` onto table testTable.  You can then use your INSERT query as follows

```
INSERT INTO testTable (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
) VALUES (
    3,
    1,
    'Original value'
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1 = VALUES(col1)
```

That would insert (3,1,'Original value') into testTable.  Following up with

```
INSERT INTO testTable (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
) VALUES (
    3,
    1,
    'New value'
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1 = VALUES(col1)
```

would then overwrite col3 and make it 'New value'

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realize it was possible. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, having a bit of a problem.  I actually didn't need the third column. Only the first two you have(I have sets of numbers per row). When I try to add those two sets of numbers in your above command it works for 3,1 but if I try to add 3,2 then I get a duplicate primary key error for col1. Makes sense but is there a way around it using both col1 and col2 as a joint type of primary key?

Comment: I've updated the example - I forgot about the PK, so have changed the PK to be col1,col2 - it will function the same for purposes of your aims of preventing duplicate col1,col2 combinations, col3 can just be thrown away if not needed

Comment: That did it! Thanks, I'll play around with it but so far its exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

to make a pair of columns unique, you declare a unique index on both columns.
something like this:

`create unique index myindex on mytable( col1, col2 )`

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNIQUE` constraint for *both* columns and use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`. Not sure what performance benefits you're talking about and where does `varchar` come from.